# Загрузка файлов в папку проекта

Tags: javascript, php

При нажатии на кнопку, должен создаваться json файл, который тут же должен отправляться в папку проекта. Как это можно реализовать?

небольшая вставка с JS кодом, где реализовывается создание файла:

```
document.getElementById("export_project").addEventListener("click", exportSceneToJSON);

  function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}

  function exportSceneToJSON(input){
    var result=scene.toJSON();
    var output =JSON.stringify(result);
    download(output, 'scene.json', '/json');
  }
```

Comment: Метка php, а код JS.. "папка проекта" находится на сервере?)

Comment: поэтому я не просто так накинул метку с PHP... мне нужно кидать файл в папку проекта, и да, я вставил код JS, чтобы люди могли понять, что это идёт создание JSON файла из сцены three js

Comment: В доке много инфы) https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.files.php
Если кратко, в глобальной переменной `$_FILES['name']` будет ваш файл) после чего сохраняйте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php